# Making a pattern 2.5 dimension for a mould making process?

Tags: modeling, topology, retopology, project

I have a detail which I wish to add to mould that I intend to slip cast, see [3D Printing a Mold for a Slipcasting Mold](https://www.instructables.com/3D-Printing-a-Mold-for-a-Mold/).

To do this I require that the model is like a displacement map eliminating any overhanging features, however I was wondering if there is an easy way of doing this while preserving my nice topology.

Here is an image of my piece in question:

[image: Green Man Detail]

Also this is an image of an overhanging detail I wish to eliminate:

[image: Overhanging Leaf]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have done this is by using a displacement modifier with a densely meshed plane and then retopologized the whole model using [this Quad Remesher addon](https://exoside.com/quadremesher/) my previous problem was the colour-space was being corrected in the displacement map image format, so I should have been using EXR format :)